# Function Pointer Issues C++ / Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino-due

i have a header file with a class and several declaration and non-static member functions like this:

```
    //foo.h
    ...
    #include <bar.h>

    class foo
    {
        ...
        public:
            void myFunction();
    };
```

and a header file with a struct and a class like:

```
    //bar.h
    ...
    struct baz
    {
         class foo;
         ...
         void (foo::*functionPointer)() = NULL;
    }

    class bar
    {
        ...
        public:
            static myOtherFunction();
    };
```

and i want to address the function pointer in bar.cpp's static function "myOtherFunction" like:

```
    void bar::myOtherFunction()
    {
        ...
        baz b = baz();
        b.functionPointer = &foo::myFunction;
    }
```

but this gets me an compiler error:

```
    bar.cpp:247:22: error: cannot convert 'void (foo::*)()' to 'void baz::foo::*)()' in assignment
          b.functionPointer = &foo*:myFunction;
    Error compiling
```

Pretty Sure that this is an obvious fault for anyone experienced in c/c++ but for now i'm stuck and would be really grateful about some help. Thank you...

Comment: Are you forward-declaring `foo` *inside* the definition of `baz`?

Comment: Iow, how does `bar.h` know `class foo` even exists? Your posted samples are full of unrelated errors, so **real** code tha exhibits the **real** problem would certainly help.

Comment: yes i did forward declare (just edited)

Comment: Its in the wrong place. Move that forward decl *outside* (above) the `baz` struct decl.

Comment: ok. that worked!!! compiler not complaining... thanks sir!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to C++11 libraries/classes in your compiler, include the `functional` library.  Description [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional).  It will show a way to make fully "packed" objects that have a reference to both the method you want, and the class instance.

If not, read the [Pointers to Members](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) section of the C++ FAQ very VERY closely.  That's supported by everything everywhere as a core part of the language.

Good luck.